# responsive html code help - display transition not working from desktop to mobile

Tags: html, mobile, stack, tablet

As you can tell from the code -  I am quite new to this.. and I am a little uncertain as to why these div's will not stack on mobile/tablet they just stay side by side. It looks fine on desktop but I would like for it to begin stacking around the tablet px range.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

```
<style>

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { #displaymobile { display:inline; background:#000000; } }

.display { display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; }
.info1 { font-size:36px;font-family:cooper-regular;line-height:90%; }
.info2 { font-size:24px;font-family:cooper-regular;line-height:90%; }
.info3 { font-size:24px;font-family:cooper-regular;line-height:90%;color:#fff; }

</style>


<main>

<div class="displaymobile">

    <div class="display">
    
    <img src="IMAGE.png" width="400" height="">

    <p style="text-align:center">
    <span class="info1">INFO1</span></br>
    <span class="info2">INFO2</span></br>
    <span class="info3">INFO3</span>
    </p>
    
    </div>

</div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is 100% as I'm newer as well but you need to set what to display the flex ( again , maybe my terminology is wrong). Try adding this in your display, it tells is to go to column instead of a row when it reaches a certain size. Cheers.

.display { display:flex; flex-direction: column; display align-items:center; justify-content:center; }

Comment: Negative, that did not work - while viewing on desktop I want to keep the the divs side by side which the way I have it now achieves that look. I have come across the flex direction info in my searching - but I only want to switch to the column view when it hits the certain px range.  

Thank you though!